# Problems with UICollectionView - one selected cell implies other selections

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, uicollectionview

In my collection view is allowed multiple selection.

When i tap an item, the system automatically select an item that is not visible.

Here's my code:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    ButtonCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ButtonCell" 
                                                                 forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *title = self.ingredientsBook.names[indexPath.item];
    cell.label.text = title;
    return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
       didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.searchButton.enabled = YES;

    ButtonCell *cell = (ButtonCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    NSString *name = self.ingredientsBook.names[indexPath.item];
    [self.selectedIngredientNames addObject:name];
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is because of cell reuse. If you don't understand that concept, then you need to read the documentation on UITableView and UICollectionView, which both reuse their cells.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you declares 2 times your cell:

```
ButtonCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ButtonCell" 
                                                             forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and:

```
ButtonCell *cell = (ButtonCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Try declare your cell in .h file and replace code which I write upper on code without class ButonCell:

```
cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ButtonCell" 
                                                             forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and:

```
cell = (ButtonCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```